# Demon Fusion in SMT: Strange Journey

Tags: smt-strange-journey

I don't really catch `Demon Fusion` concept in the game. Then I select 2 demons, the expected result shown seems to be other demon that is somewhat equivalent or even of lower level than demons. Thus it seems illogical to lose 2 demons to get same other.

But I think that I just don't get something with this function, from the description it seems to be powerful and important game feature. Can someone clarify this?

Comment: I don't want to put this as an answer, since I haven't played Strange Journey.

I have however played SMT: Lucifer's Call and in that game, from what I've seen there's several rules that apply to demon fusion.

First off, most demons have a limit to their abilities. A high level demon casting Zio is nice, but you'd rather have a demon cast Ziodyne.

Secondly, in Lucifer's Call you could only have a limited amount of demons in your party, so naturally you want the strongest demons. Idealy creating strong and versatile demons. (Demon with Agi + Demon with Zio turning into Demon with both)

Comment: @J.C thanks, that was helpful. I think that you can safely put this as answer, since core logic is probably very similar between the games. That's the difference between `Zio` and `Ziodyne`, I have not seen latter mentioned in the game yet.

Comment: Two demons of the same family create the next strongest in the family, so some fusions create much stronger demons. However the levels are not the primary reason to fuse. That would be the skill transfers mentioned in the answer

Comment: Yes, in SMT games, fusions are often sideways trades unless you just happen to match up the right demons to fuse, which will then make the next tier of the demon instead.  I suggest you looking up a fusion chart to see how to fuse stronger demons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, I haven't played Strange Journey, so there might be some differences between the Fusion systems used in the game.

The main and first reason why you'd want to fuse demons is to gain stronger demons. A lot of demons don't learn new skills after a certain level, and they usually don't evolve either, so what this means is that demons have a limit on their abilities and stats.

So, taking for example, Hua Po can learn Agi and Maragi, but after that it doesn't learn Agilao or Maragion. Being a weaker demon means Hua Po will end up with low stats, but more importantly, not having actual stronger abilities means that you'll end up having a huge disadvantage later in the game.

The question that arises after that would probably be "Why fuse, if you can persuade them to join you?". The answer would be the following, even though I'm not sure if they all apply to Strange Journey:

1. Some demons are only available through fusing.
2. Fusing two weaker demons into the one you want is sometimes easier than persuading. Some demons are persuaded easier than others.
3. Just like weaker demons, stronger demons have a limited set of abilities. Perhaps you're trying to replace your demon who is focused on attacking with Fire damage, but that demon happens to have a crucial healing ability for your party. It should be possible to fuse your way to that new demon + keep this ability. This often depends on luck and compatibility.
4. Since you have a limited amount of demons for your party, you'll want to have the elite demons with together forming a sort of all-rounder party. Perhaps have one easily switchable one(Say, Demon A with Agi and Demon B with Zio or Bufu). This correlates to 3, where you try to make a party with each having several skills for varying situations.

I'm not sure if the latter reasons can be applied to Strange Journey, but I hope this helps :D

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much same in Strange Journey. I fugured most parts myself already it's was actually obvious I should just pay more attention to details on screen.